# How to change a button from curved corner to sharp?

Tags: css

I need to change a button on my website's homepage from a curved edge to sharp.

It is a WordPress website and I am trying to add this code via Additional CSS window.

I tried to perform the below code, but it did not work.

```
wobble-horizontal.shop-button.arrow-right.style2.black.bg-white
{ 
  border:3px solid #bada55;
}
```

[image]

Any suggestion on how to make the button sharp-edged?

Edit: I have just realised I haven't mentioned "a" class at the beginning. It should be `a.wobble`. Sorry for the confusion.
[image]

Comment: `border-radius: 0px;` will solve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that's just a div, it's as simple as setting the `border-radius` to `0px`

Also, the library you're using could be high up in specificity, so you can also try `border-radius: 0px !important;` to try and force it.

Based on your `border: 3px solid #bada55` line, I think you may have the wrong selector as that should be setting the border of that button a lime green and not gray.

```css
#sharp {
  border-radius: 0px;
}

#not-sharp {
  border-radius: 10px;
}
div { background: red; margin: 10px; }
```

```html
<div id="sharp">My Sharp Button</div>
<div id="not-sharp">My Not Sharp Button</div>
```

Comment: Your selector is probably wrong. Can you try and do something obvious to the button to see if you have the correct selector? Try doing `display: none` or changing the background or giving it some astronomical number for a width.

Comment: You're right on the money @mwilson. I tried to hide the button and it is not working either, but I was wondering what is the issue since I get the class name properly as the screenshot depicts. https://imgur.com/cbvxayO

Comment: Yea, you're selector is incorrect. Please mark as answer.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be another CSS script that is manipulating the `border-radius` property.

To have sharp borders, use:

```
border-radius: 0;
```

The code you were using just sets the border's thickness (3px), style (solid fill), and color(#bada55), not the radius.

If this does not do it, try tracing down what other CSS script is manipulating the border radius, or just use the `!important` directive to override:

```
border-radius: 0 !important;
```

Comment: I did that. The button is not changing at all for some reason. :/

Comment: @Simon Try tracing down that other CSS script (there must be one), or use `!important`. Answer edited.

Answer (score 1):

```
border-radius: 0;
```

or `border-radius: 0 !important;` if your CSS is being overridden.

Answer (score 0):

Setting border-radius to 0px should give you straight edges on the button